# How to fire a focusin event in a crossbrowser way?

Tags: javascript, focus, dom-events, focusin

I've found very hard to manually trigger a `focusin` event using just Javascript (no jQuery) for it for a test suite.

Apparently when the browser does not have the focus (that can happen only in tests) I want to simulate the `focusin` event myself.

I've found that the `CustomEvent` constructor works

```
var event = new CustomEvent('focusin', { bubbles: true, cancelable: false });
this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

but I need to make this IE9+. The old-fashioned way doesn't seems to work.

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('focusin', true, false);
this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

AFAIK those two constructions should be equivalent in functionality, but clearly that's not true. Tested in Chrome/Firefox/Safari when the browser's window doesn't have the focus.

Is there something wrong in the second snippet?

Comment: is focusin right? I thought it was just focus.

Comment: @thelastshadow: `focusin` is the version of `focus` that bubbles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin

Comment: Yes, it is. That's why I specify `bubble: true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if the element has children by calling focus() on the firstElementChild.

```js
let el = document.getElementById('myDivId');
el.firstElementChild.focus();
```

This will trigger focusin on the div and bubble up to any of the div's parents.